# Numpy: Find Sequence in Sparse Array, Ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large 1D array containing mostly NaNs and a few integers.
I'm trying to extract the start and end indices where the array contains a specific sequence, ignoring intermediate NaNs.
For example:

```
sequence = np.array([1, 2, 3])
sparse_array1 = np.array([np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, 1, 1, np.nan])
sparse_array2 = np.array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1])

print(find_sequence_indices(sparse_array1, sequence))
# prints [(4, 7), (12, 18)]

print(find_sequence_indices(sparse_array2, sequence))
# prints []
```

I couldn't think of a way that did not involve 3 nested loops. My array is much larger than the example, I can't afford cubed run times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), indexing and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

def find_sequence_indices(sparse_array, sequence):
    N = len(sequence)
    m = np.isnan(sparse_array)

    # get only indices of non-NA
    idx = np.where(~m)[0]
    # find position of sequence
    idx2 = (swv(sparse_array[idx], N) == sequence).all(axis=1)
    # get start/end
    return list(zip(idx[:1-N][idx2], idx[N-1:][idx2]))

find_sequence_indices(sparse_array1, sequence)
# [(4, 7), (12, 18)]

find_sequence_indices(sparse_array2, sequence)
# []
```

Intermediates (for `sparse_array1`):

```
# idx
array([ 1,  2,  4,  5,  7,  8, 11, 12, 16, 18, 19, 20])

# sparse_array1[idx]
array([2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 1.])

# swv(sparse_array1[idx], N)
array([[2., 3., 1.],
       [3., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3.],  # match, index 4
       [2., 3., 2.],
       [3., 2., 3.],
       [2., 3., 1.],
       [3., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3.],  # match, index 12
       [2., 3., 1.],
       [3., 1., 1.]])

# (swv(sparse_array1[idx], N) == sequence).all(axis=1)
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False])
```